# Unsupported class file major version 61 error with jobrunr

Tags: java, gradle, jobrunr

I am trying to use jobrunr with java 17. However, I am getting Unsupported class file major version 61 error while doing the same with the line
`JobId jobId = BackgroundJob.schedule(runAt, () -> helper.excuteTaskAction();`
Does jobrunr not support java 17? If it does can anyone help me figure out why a conflict is arising here? I am using the package jobrunr-spring-boot-starter:5.3.1.

I tried downgrading to java 8, which scheduled jobs without errors. However, I would very much like to keep working with java 17. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: Are you sure you are running application with Java 17? It looks like you compile code with Java 17 and try to run it with older version.

Comment: @Pekinek I am compiling and running the code using gradle clean build and gradle bootRun respectively. The jdk installed in my machine is 17. The java version shown within gradle -version also is 17. Is there something else I can check to verify that it is not the case?

Comment: What version of ASM are you using?

Comment: I am using asm 7.0. As of now, I downgraded to java 11 and now the jobs are getting scheduled fine without version conflicts. But if we are able to resolve this issue, we still would prefer java 17.